# Combination of Conditional Expectations

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(T,S,\theta)$ be random variables in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with joint pdf noted by $f_{T, S ,\theta}(\cdot)$

I want to know if $E[\theta|T\geq t,S\geq s]= \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{t}^{\infty}  \int_{s}^{\infty} \theta f_{T, S ,\theta}(t,S, \theta) \;dS \, dT\,d\theta}{\int_{t}^{\infty}\int_{s}^{\infty} f_{T ,S}(T,S)\;dS \, dT}$ can be expressed as a combination of the expectations noted A and B below:

\begin{align} A = E[\theta|T=t,S\geq s]&=\frac{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{s}^{\infty} \theta f_{T, S ,\theta}(t,S, \theta) \;dS \,d\theta}{\int_{s}^{\infty} f_{T ,S}(t,S)\;dS}\\
B = E[\theta|T\geq t,S=s]&=\frac{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{t}^{\infty} \theta f_{T, S ,\theta}(T,s, \theta) \;dS \,d\theta}{\int_{t}^{\infty} f_{T ,S}(T,s)\;dT}
\end{align}

I have in mind (though cannot show) something like a linear combination of A and B, for example, if one assumes that $(\theta,T,S)$ follow a multivariate Gaussian distribution

Comment: "Truncation" is not the same thing as "conditioning". The expression $E[\theta|T\geq t,S\geq s]$ is an expression of the expected value of $\theta$ conditional on two other r.v.'s being greater or equal to a specific lower limit. This is not a "truncated expectation". Clarify, perhaps?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: Thanks. You are right.  That was a careless use of terms. I meant the expectation of a truncated distribution (where I am using the term as it would be used, for example, here: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)). What do you think about changing the title of the question to: "Expectation of a truncated multivariate distribution as a function of the truncation margins"? Or do you have maybe a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. The problem is with notation, and with how things change when two or more rv's are present, compared with the univariate case. When only one rv is present then using the standard conditioning notation "|" to indicate truncation of the domain is ok, because, exactly, no other rv is present.

Consider now two rv's $X$ and $Y$ with pdf's $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, and cdf's $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$, ranging both in $(-\infty, \infty)$.

The expression $E(X\mid Y \ge a)$ *always means*

$$E(X\mid Y \ge a) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y\ge a)dx=\frac {1}{f_Y(y\mid y\ge a)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{XY}(x,y\ge a)dx$$

and it is verbally described as a *conditional* expected value - it is a mistake (confusing) to call it "truncated".
Also, as you can see, $Y$ is not integrated out, and it shouldn't: conditional expected values are a function of the conditioning variable.

Now, as far as I can tell, your RHS is a legitimate expression that is described as "the expected value of $\theta$ w.r.t to the joint distribution with truncated $T$ and $S$"  - but  I don't think that we have a short-hand notation for that... perhaps, something like

$$E_{\theta \tilde T\tilde S}(\theta) ??$$

where we use the subscript in $E$ to denote that we apply the joint density, and the tilde denote the truncated versions of $T$ and $S$? In any case, don't go with the "conditional" notation, people will understand something else.

Comment: Sorry but the notations $f_{X|Y}(x|y\ge a)$, $f_Y(y\mid y\ge a)$ and $f_{XY}(x,y\ge a)$ are not canonical. If you ask me, this is for good reasons and they should be avoided.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulus: Perhaps the title can be changed if "Truncated Multivariate Distribution" is confusing. However, beyond this point, my question remains unanswered: is it possible to rewrite the integrals in the first equation, as a combination of the integrals in the lines below?  I'll edit the question so that it is  perhaps clearer.